# Placing an image to the right, inside an input box

Tags: html, css

How can I get my double down arrow image positioned to the right inside my input box and It must also be clickable.

Here is my image: [image]

And Here is a picture of the desired result:[image]

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <img src="double_arrow.png" style="width: 19px; height: 18px;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What action to call when it clicked ?

Comment: Is it a text with right side arrow or should it be a drop-down list?

Comment: text with right side arrow. I will do something with it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap them both in an outer container that is positioned relatively.  Then set the image to be absolute position and anchored to the right

```
<div class="combo">
  <input type="text">
  <img class="trigger">
</div>

.combo { position: relative; }
.combo .trigger { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 1px }
```

Something to that effect ought to work

Comment: I'd say the same thing. Prepared a demo for this, so i leave it here;) http://jsfiddle.net/59mTF/

Comment: The width of the div should be relative to the width of the input box and not 100% width, how do you fix this?